# .htaccess URL is being cut at a space (I'm using Codeigniter)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've used the following code to map https://live.example.com on to http://example.com/api

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^live\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.+)$ "http://example.com/api/$1" [L,P]
```

The following url:

```
https://live.example.com/userlinks/xml/John%20James/MvPjeUTo15/
```

Is suppose to map onto:

```
http://example.com/api/userlinks/xml/John%20James/MvPjeUTo15/
```

Instead it maps it to:

```
http://example.com/api/userlinks/xml/John
```

So it seems to cut it at the space. I am using the Codeigniter framework but I am not sure if the problem lies there.

Also using `%20` or just a space in the url bar produces no different results.

Anyone any idea and/or solution why this happens?

Thank you very much,

Ice

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed:

Added to apache2.conf (httpd.conf):

```
RewriteMap escapemap int:escape
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^live\.domain\.com" [NC]
RewriteRule "(.*)$" "http://domain.com/api/${escapemap:$1}" [L,P]
```

*source: http://www.nabble.com/Re%3A-Re-users%40httpd--writeRule%2C--P--and-space-on-URL-p15632475.html*

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, without modifying the httpd file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) http://domain.com/api/$1 [R=302,NC]
```

Notice how the rule does not capture the end of the line.